# purrr - use full list-elements in map call

Tags: r, purrr

Having the following list:

```
dat <- list(words = c("foo", "bar", "howdy"), 
        pattern=c(foobar="foo|bar", cowboy="howdy"), 
        furterdat=1)
```

I would like to do the following in a pipe-style way

```
require(purrr)
require(stringr)
map(dat$pattern, ~str_detect(dat$words, .))
```

I tried thinks like

```
dat %>% map(.$pattern, ~str_detect, string=.$words)
dat %>% lmap(.$pattern, ~str_detect, string=.$words)
```

But couldn't get the result i want. Any ideas?

Comment: `stringi` (the underpinning of `stringr`) is vectorized over both `str` and `pattern` if that helps at al.

Comment: @hrbrmstr That is true, but i am not sure how this could/should help. The target is to apply each pattern to all words. `str_detect(dat$words, dat$pattern)` is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an option:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dat <- list(words = c("foo", "bar", "howdy"), 
        pattern=c(foobar="foo|bar", cowboy="howdy"), 
        furterdat=1)

dat$pattern %>% map(str_detect, dat$words)

#> $foobar
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> 
#> $cowboy
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```